# Duplicate newtonsoft.json.jsonproperty attribute

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I want to use attribute on property if JSON property is "given_name" or "first_name" then use this property like below code but it generate error: Duplicate newtonsoft.json.jsonproperty attribute

Below is my code:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("given_name")]
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("first_name")]
public string firstName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the meaning of attribute wrongly. `JsonProperty` Attribute maps the serialized property name to .net property. You cannot serialize same property twice. What you can have a wrapper over one property to serialize it twice.

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("first_name")]
public string firstName { get; set; }
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("given_name")]
public string GivenName { get { return firstName; } set { firstName = value; } }
```

Comment: But I don't know json property it's generate at runtime so either be "first_name" or "given_name" any one of two, so I want to use OR operator  on them how to use

Comment: Same effect. If you receive JSON with either `{ "first_name":  }` or `{"given_name": }` the above code works as well.